# Visualforce dynamic custom components: Type.forname no longer works

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm trying to use the method @DanielBlackhall gave in this question:
[Loading a custom component into a Visualforce page dynamically](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/loading-a-custom-component-into-a-visualforce-page-dynamically)

But unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore:

```
Type t = Type.forName('Component.c.MyCustomComponent');
```

always returns null.

Comment: I'm guessing the question is, how do you get it to work?

Comment: @JesseAltman I think the question is how do you do Load a custom component into a Visualforce page dynamically now that the type.forname method doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the `Type.forName` method has limitations and can't be used with Visualforce Components :-( I raised this exact Case to Salesforce and they advised me the same and that it was "out of scope".

Daniel Blackhall very kindly tried his original code again and confirmed we now can't get anything other than `null`. It can only invoke Primitives, sObjects, Collections and Apex types per [the docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm).

(You can almost get there [with a big hammer like this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/61252/320), but it's not truly dynamic.)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that on another forum I think. The thing is... I thought I actually had it working last week. Also, apparently, someone else did too. Just making sure I haven't missed anything stupid.

Comment: What is the case number? I have had good luck getting things fixed when they are raised by multiple partners.

Comment: @grigriforce 08493365 - I'll send you a slab of chocolate if you can convince them!

Comment: @user31 I will definitely give it my best shot. Very annoying as I don't see an alternate method of doing this if type.forname doesn't work.

Comment: Beer too if they'll make `ApexPages.Component` a supported `@RemoteAction` return type as well ;-)