# Dynamically injecting Visualforce markup into component

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, dynamiccomponent

I have an issue where I am trying to render a component on a VF page where I don't know if the component exists in the org or not until run time (I am trying to use a dynamic component on the front end). Since I can't assume it exists by default, I can't reference the component like so:

```
Component.some_namespace.MyComponent myComp = new Component.some_namespace.MyComponent();
```

as that won't compile.

I can query the component using SOQL and even get its markup, but can I do anything with the VF markup I get? Could I create a wrapper component and inject the markup somehow? I guess like...

```
Component.c.WrapperComponent wrapComp = new Component.c.WrapperComponent();
wrapComp.vfMarkup = queriedComponent.Markup;
```

it's frustrating because the queried component is of type `ApexComponent` (a metadata type) but the dynamic component requires an object of type `ApexPages.Component`. There's no way I can convert the `ApexComponent` to a `ApexPages.Component`, right?

Comment: I think Type.forName might be the answer, but I can't seem o make it work either.

Comment: @sfdcfox from what I've seen from other questions/answers on SE, Type.forName _used_ to work but Salesforce decided to close that loop hole or something...

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50295 is a workaround... requires additional code post-deploy, but it can be done.