# Render A component dynamically

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component

I have requirement to display component dynamically, I get the component name in list. Using list name I have to render the component, for now I have taken one component (i.e. `component1`).

I have render that component inside a Visualforce page. Code is as below. Please advise.

**Visualforce Component**

```
<apex:component>
<div>
   <h1>Component 1 </h1>
</div>
</apex:component>
```

**Visualforce page**

```
<apex:page controller="cntr" >
    <c:{!compName} />
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class cntr {
    public String compName { get; private set; }
    public cntr() {
        compName = "component1"
    }
}
```

### Updated

Considering your answer, i tried Same on component1.

- Keeping **"component1"** same.

**Apex Page**

```
<apex:page  controller="comcntr">
    <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!createComponent}"/>    
</apex:page>
```

**controller**

```
public class comcntr {
    public comcntr() { }
    public Component.c.component1 getCreateComponent() {           
        Component.c.component1 myDy = new Component.c.component1();
        return myDY;        
    }
}
```

this working for me now .

But my requirement is like, inside the controller i have the property called **compName** it is holding my component name. i wanted render that component.

```
  public class comcntr {
        public String compName='component1';
        public comcntr() { }
        public Component.c.component1 getCreateComponent() {           
            Component.c.component1 myDy = new Component.c.component1();
            return myDY;     

        }
    }
```

By taking **comName** value as component name,  i have to  return the the component. Can you suggest how can achieve this? My **compName** is always changes depending on requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you cannot make a component dynamic in Visualforce but you have an option to do it by apex.

Refer- [Creating and Displaying Dynamic Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm)

> **Dynamic Custom Components**
>
> Using custom components dynamically works exactly the same as the
>   standard Visualforce components. Just change the namespace to that of
>   the custom component. Your custom components are in the c namespace,
>   so you can create one dynamically like this:
>
> ```
> Component.c.MyCustomComponent myDy = 
>     new Component.c.MyCustomComponent();
> ```
>
> As a convenience for your own
>   components, you can omit the namespace, like so:
>
> ```
> Component.MyCustomComponent myDy = 
>     new Component.MyCustomComponent();
> ```
>
> If you are using components provided by
>   a third party in a package, use the namespace of the package provider:
>
> ```
> Component.TheirName.UsefulComponent usefulC = 
>     new Component.TheirName.UsefulComponent();
> ```

Comment: i had gone through this link before. i had tried too. its working when i know exact name of component at the beginning, let update question on your answer @rahul

Comment: Lets say even if its possible to do this in Visualforce page, you would still need to know the component name in advance; otherwise you would have run time exception.

Comment: please find updated question .

Comment: my project requirement is like that.  menu generated dynamically . in feature menu can be added, so when new menu is attached new component is created related to menu. menu name and component name is always same in my requirement. when menu is clicked by taking menu name as component name, i have to render component based on menu click .

Comment: Refer [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/61252/4726) answer

Comment: This example is good,  i think this is a solution for my problem. Thank You so much .