# Dynamic initialization of custom visualforce components

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

Visualforce has initialization of visualforce components in apex. For example MyCustomComponent component:
ApexPages.Component customComponent = new Component.c.MyCustomComponent();

Is that possible to pass dynamically the component name instead of using Component.c.MyCustomComponent? I want to build a method that can get component name dynamically from the custom setting and initialize new ApexPages.Component.

Answer (score -1):

This could require some dynamic Apex. 
Use `Type.forName` Apex Method to instantiate your component

```
Type componentType = 'Component.c.MyCustomComponent';
ApexPages.Component = (ApexPages.Component)componentType.newInstance();
```

Comment: did you mean: Type componentType = Type.forName('Component.c.MyCustomComponent'); ? If yes – it returns null in componentType.

Comment: ok, this approach seems not working anymore. So probably as workaround you may put additional factory class in between that will have method to create desired component. Check this question from 2014 

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50295/dynamic-components-on-a-visualforce-page