# display VF component based on variable value

Tags: visualforce-component

We have a custom object called "Container" and each Container item is associated to a specific VF Component.  On the Container record, you would select from a picklist the VF component it associates with to.

In the VF page, the component would be called based on this value.

In a perfect world, any component on any visualforce page could call the appropriate Container.

This is what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
<c:{!Container.Component_Name__c} />
```

I know that doing `if{!Container.Component_Name__c} == 'this' do 'that'` would work, but this is not ideal because there are many components!

thanks so much for your time

Comment: Is there a controller thats setting the component_name__c? how are you toggling the value of component_name__c field?

Comment: @rao the component_name__c is just a value set on the container record, which is sent from the controller to the component.  On the record, component_name__c is indeed the name of the component.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked previously here :

[Loading a custom component into a Visualforce page dynamically](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/loading-a-custom-component-into-a-visualforce-page-dynamically)

So this might (or) might not help you. I have introduced if loops but not sure if there is another way.

I am not aware of any way to dynamically construct an apex tag.

I took the approach of controlling the component to display in the controller where we have much control to do what we want.

Thanks to @sfdcfox. Based on this question I constructed the answer with a bit twist to accommodate what you are looking for:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000092Y5IAI

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="comp_test_controller">
 <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!headerComponent }"/>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class comp_test_controller {

    public transient ApexPages.Component headerComponent { get; set; }

    public comp_test_controller(){
        Type t = Type.forName('MyComponent');
        if(t != null) {
            for( ApexPages.Component cust : ((CustomComponentManager)t.newInstance()).newComponent()){          
                //In your case you will compare cust with the Component_Name__c value.
                if(string.valueof(cust) == 'Component.sitelogin'){
                    this.headerComponent = cust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class to support type.forname:

Previously type.forname('') used to support components, but it supports only apex class instances now.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm

```
    public class MyComponent implements CustomComponentManager {
    public List<ApexPages.Component> newComponent() {
        List<ApexPages.Component> comp_list = new List<ApexPages.Component>();
        comp_list.add(new Component.c.SiteLogin());
    return comp_list;
    }
    }
```

Interface:

```
global interface CustomComponentManager {
      List<ApexPages.Component> newComponent();
    }
```

Comment: thank you for this! this is very interesting.  I'll report back if we utilize this approach

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: @YankiTwizzy what was your issue, can you post as a new question

Comment: @rao http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51661/dynamic-variable-passed-as-componentvalue-on-apexdynamiccomponent