# Issue with passing different value as ComponentValue in apex:dynamic Component inside apex:repeat tag

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

I am facing an issue. When i am putting `<apex:dynamicComponent id="dynamicComp" componentValue="{!clauseList.dynamicCompName}" invokeAfterAction="true">` inside `<apex:repeat>` tag only the last component which is in "clauseList" getting rendered on VF Page.

All other dynamic component in clauseList getting override by Last components in the "clauseList".

Let say I have 2 dynamicComponent DynamicCustomComponent & DynamicCustomComponentNew when I am putting apex:dynamicComponent Tag inside `<apex:repeat/>` tag the output always return component which is added in last in wrapper list. So in this case "DynamicCustomComponentNew" is added in last to the wrapper list so the output comes as below -

> **Output -

1. This is Dynamic Component New
2. This is Dynamic Component New**

> **Ideally Output should be as follows-

1. This is Dynamic Component
2. This is Dynamic Component New**

Controller Code -

```
public List<ContractClauseWrapperNew> getContractClauseWrapperListNew(){
    List<ContractClauseWrapperNew> ContractClauseWrapperList1 = new List<ContractClauseWrapperNew>();
    ContractClauseWrapperList1.add(new ContractClauseWrapperNew(new Component.c.DynamicCustomComponent()));
    ContractClauseWrapperList1.add(new ContractClauseWrapperNew(new Component.c.DynamicCustomComponentNew()));

    return ContractClauseWrapperList1;
}
```

Wrapper Class -

```
public class ContractClauseWrapperNew{        
    public ApexPages.Component dynamicCompName {get;set;}

    public ContractClauseWrapperNew(ApexPages.Component dynamicCompName){
        this.dynamicCompName = dynamicCompName;
    }
}
```

VF Page Code -

```
<apex:repeat value="{!contractClauseWrapperListNew}" var="clauseList">
    apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!clauseList.dynamicCompName}" invokeAfterAction="true"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: If you could elaborate your question along with your code then probably members can guide you properly.

Comment: @SantanuBoral: I have updated issue description and sample code to replicate.

Comment: I think you have to use contractClauseWrapperListNew in apex:repeat

Comment: Sorry its a typo error. I am using contractClauseWrapperListNew in apex:repeat Tag. I have corrected VF Page Code.

Comment: rather than looping through apex:repeat, you can build the dataList in controller and display the dynamic component  without repeat in VFP. Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to build components together inside your Apex controller and deliver it to the page as a single dynamicComponent, otherwise you will end up seeing duplicate last items which has been entered into the list.

This question has already answer for you:

[Pass different values as componentvalue to apex:dynamiccomponent in apex:repeat](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51661/pass-different-values-as-componentvalue-to-apexdynamiccomponent-in-apexrepe)

For more information, refer [Creating and Displaying Dynamic Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm)

Comment: That answer only suites if you dont have complex logic involved. In that case you can create everything inside apex and served as a single component to VF Page. In my scenario it wont work bcoz on my VF Page i have several sections and those sections are generated dynamically based on certain conditions. For example in some scenario the total sections are 3 but for other scenario it may be any number. And inside those sections i need to display different different tables and those table also have some business logic involved. Also, its not predefined whether all section contains table or not.