# Getting a VF component dynamically by name in Apex

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component, dynamiccomponent

I am trying to use Apex to control which component to show inside a `<apex:dynamicComponent>` but I don't want to hardcode the component names. So my question is, how can I reference the component by name dynamically in Apex? Is there a map/list somewhere that returns all components that I can then iterate over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After exhaustively searching around this topic I finally found what appears to be the answer:

[Loading a custom component into a Visualforce page dynamically](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/loading-a-custom-component-into-a-visualforce-page-dynamically)

[Dynamic components on a Visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50295/dynamic-components-on-a-visualforce-page)

P.S. I have been searching using variations of "dynamic visualforce" as keywords but none had returned the above thread. In fact it wasn't only after I googled for "ApexPages.Component abstract class" that I saw it!

Answer (score 0):

You could query the ApexComponent object. This will give you all VF components available.

I would suggest some sort of naming convention for the ones you would like to have available for dynamic use. This way you can separate them from other VF components

Comment: Do you know if I can get an instance of the component as well?